# Firebase deployment issue

Tags: reactjs, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

[image]

I'm trying to deploy my web app to Firebase, and I have gotten through the deploy script successfully, but when I go to the url I get the Open Hosting Documentation page instead of my app.
This my firebase.json file.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "y",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to change the value of "public" from "y" to "build" lets see

Comment: You are welcome. Please approve my answer. Thank you!

Comment: Done thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the value of "public" from "y" to "build"